# How can I stop the transparent background of multiline text overlapping between lines?

Tags: javascript, html, css, text-rendering

I'm facing an issue where I have an inline `<span>` containing multiline text, with a transparent background. Despite having a default line-height, the background on the text overlaps, causing darker, horizontal rows where the background is overlaid onto itself.

#### Here is a good demonstration of the problem (image + jsfiddle)

[image]

[JsFiddle demonstrating this issue.](http://jsfiddle.net/cc3ccfaa/1/)

#### Minimal reproduction of issue

**HTML:**

```
<h1>
    <span>Although it is set to a line height of 1, the background behind text still overlaps between rows.</span> 
</h1>
```

**CSS:**

```
h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Arial;
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 30px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline;
}
h1 span {
    position: relative;
}
```

#### Solution requirements

1. The background color must conform to the shape of the text; so setting the `span` to `display:inline-block` is not a workable solution.
2. Setting a fixed `line-height` (or `padding`) is not an optimal answer as the exact font rendering changes between browsers, and user's settings. Setting the `line-height` perfectly in Chrome will product an imperfect result in Firefox, for example.
3. The text must be dynamic and semantic. A solution cannot involve rendering an image representation of the text on the server for the client.
4. Preferably allows for arbitrary `padding` to be added or removed to reduce or increase the space between the text and the edge of the background.
5. Javascript could be fine. I'm using Angular 2 here, so answers which integrate nicely with that are even better.

Comment: Any reason for the driveby downvote(s!) on what I think is a well-formed question?

Comment: You should include the code in the question (not that I driveby downvoteed)

Comment: Why not just get rid of the line height then?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith - can't plus two that comment, sometimes it's the simplest things :p

Comment: Not a fixed `line-height` but a calculated version => `height`/`font-size` = `line-height`. But it seems like the `display: inline` takes an extra 1.5 pixels on each side => 33/30 = 1.1 for line-height.

Comment: @TimVermaelen has the answer 1.1 or 33px for line-height

Comment: [Leading and Half Leading](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/visudet.html#q22) ... Basically your line height value is less than the font size. this gets the line box to bleed into the adjacent glyphs' `line-box` .. @TimVermaelen has the value you need. That or `1.09999999`

Answer (score 0):

Line height will accept a 'none' value, so you can set that and it works (if it's display:block), however (at least in chrome, safari and ff on Mac) anything inline had a 1px gap between the lines.  So in the solution below I just added a padding top of 1px to the span to adjust for that gap.  I'ts a little hacky, but it gets the job done.  You'll want to do much more browser testing obviously. It scales fairly well with browser zoom on chrome and ff, but gets a little off at really large zoom rates on safari.

```css
h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Arial;
    line-height: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #FFF;
}
h1 span {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  line-height: inherit;
  display: inline;
  padding-top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<h1>
    <span>Although it is set to a line height of 1, the background behind text still overlaps between rows.</span> 
</h1>
```

Comment: I appreciate your time to make an answer, but this solution just moves the "have to get it perfect everywhere" problem from line-height to padding-top.  For example, your solution does not work on the very first browser I checked: FF on Windows.

Comment: Interesting Bill. I just pulled this page up in Windows 10 with Firefox 55, ran the snippet and it displays correctly.  I get that it's not a perfect answer, but sometimes there never are.  Especially considering the plethora of devices, browsers, and all their nuances.  Sometimes you have to make do with what works, as disappointing as that may be.  Cheers.