# CSS: Transparent background-color on multi-line text, without ugly overlap or space between lines

Tags: html, css

I am overlaying white text with a semi-transparent background over an image.  For single lines, this works great.  However, when the text is multi-line, the transparent background overlaps the lines below and above and create an ugly box in between each line where the overlap occurs.  Nor do I want empty space in between lines either, say if the line height is large -- I'm looking for a uniform transparent background in the shape of the text.

Here's an codepen example of the overlap in action:

https://codepen.io/haydentech/pen/oeQpXe

```
<h1 class="padded-multiline">
  <span>How can I have multiline text with a transparent background, without these ugly boxes between lines?</span>
</h1>
```

.

```
.padded-multiline { 
  line-height: 1.4; 
  padding: 2px 0; 
  width: 400px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.padded-multiline span { 
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #fff; 
  display: inline;
  padding: 0.45rem;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, lightblue, yellow);
}
```

If the line-height were calculated *perfectly* (1.63 in the above example), then there would be no overlap or empty space between lines.  However, getting that calculated perfectly down to the pixel on all browsers is a fool's errand, so I'm not really interested in going there, especially since my font size may vary between desktop and mobile.

Comment: Using inline-block would kill that problem but would not make every line being an inline... I assume that would not work for you?

Comment: @carlos-alves-jorge I'd prefer to have the ragged edge that inline gives me, but inline-block is the only proposed method that actually gives usable results.

Answer (score 0):

If using inline-block doesn't cut the deal for your, a good hack would be to use box-shadow to complete the "unfilled" holes between lines:

```
.padded-multiline span { 
  box-shadow: 0 -5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),0 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  line-height:150%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #fff; 
  display: inline;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

Comment: The answer on this post could also work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39238429/how-can-i-stop-the-transparent-background-of-multiline-text-overlapping-between

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but using box-shadow just moves the "have to get it just perfect on all browsers" problem from the line-height to the box-shadow, and doesn't address the overlapping lines issue at all.  I think I may have to just stick with inline-block, unfortunately.